# PHP fast-cgi redirect loop apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, debian-jessie, php5

Before anyone points out "why use X version of PHP" here is a short rundown; TL:DR it's temporary, I have to.

The company I'm doing this "migration" for needs 5.3 with two sites that are running on an old in-house built CMS. The company split a while back and their side does not have the new CMS. These sites still need to be maintained until they can be taken off the CMS. At the same time they need 5.6 available to run their new sites. Yes I would have simply set up a virtual machine and installed 5.3 from the wheezy repo, but I cannot do that In this situation.
Anyhow I'm running Debian Jessie and after compiling and installing 5.3.10, I attempted to get apache to use it via fast-cgi. I am however getting a 500 and the following error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error.

Traceback:

http://pastebin.com/SGu0a8Ua

Here is my configuration:

Contents of `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php53-cgi`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC="/etc/php53/apache2/"
export PHPRC
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /usr/bin/php53/php-cgi
```

Contents of `/etc/apache2/php53.conf`:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
ScriptAlias /php53-cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php53-cgi
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /php53-cgi
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Finally in the vhost for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Include php53.conf
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you simple set:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

In the php.ini your CGI instance is using.